# Set Font based on Direction in CSS

Tags: css, wordpress, fonts, themes, right-to-left

I'm using Wordpress.

Is it possible to set a font-family for RTL text and headers (I'm not using WPML or Polylang, just text aligned to right and written in Arabic), different from the one my theme uses as default? ie. keep the default font of my template for English language, but use a different font for text and headers (h1, h2…) aligned to right (or written in RTL language like Arabic and Hebrew).

How do I do that using my themes's style.css or a custom css?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This is tricky, and it really depends on what exactly you want to achieve and how you do it. You can, however, take advantage of the fact that RTL blocks (and inline text) uses the `dir="rtl"` property to set a general CSS rule that captures the elements that have those properties.

For example:

```
<h1 dir="rtl">עברית</h1>
```

And then add a CSS rule like this:

```
*[dir="rtl"] {
  font-family: serif;
}
```

This isn't perfect and you might have to have some adjustments, but it could at least do the trick. You need to make sure all of your RTL text is defined with `dir="rtl"` -- which is a good practice regardless, and what W3C recommendations are.

You can check [this jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mLnr7oks/) as an example (I added colors to the rule to show how it affects the relevant RTL pieces).